# Do i need to install entity framework every time when i used mvc 4 with ef..?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

i have done one demo project on mvc 4 using entity framework and heading to second on, but when i use DbContext class i get error like : 
The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
Even if i added System.Data.Entity.dll...
When search on internet, many told to install entity framework from Nu get, but i install it in previous project. So do i need to install it every time when i use MVC using EF..??
Anyone please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuget does not install packages on your machine, it downloads and references it in the individual project you are adding it to.

So yes, you need to add EF to each project you want to use it on.

Comment: So it means if i am not connected to internet and i am going to start new project in MVC using EF then i can't use it..??

Comment: No, it means if you aren't connected to the internet you cannot use nuget to download new packages or package updates.   However if you've already downloaded EF for another project, there's nothing stopping you from copying the DLL and referencing it in your project.  I highly recommend getting and reading some books that will teach you how to use nuget and visual studio.