# Is really necessary to install Entity Framework in every project in which dbcontext it's been used

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, nuget-package

I usually create a class library to hold entity framework models and add a reference of it to the other(s) project(s) where it's required. Nevertheless I find annoying adding a reference to entity framework too. I think it should not be requiered  Is there a way to avoid that pain? Thank you very much for you time :)

Comment: Yes, it it necessary.

Comment: Yes, you need to add EF to each project you want to use it on.
[Check it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314227/do-i-need-to-install-entity-framework-every-time-when-i-used-mvc-4-with-ef)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, anywhere that uses your db context must know what entity framework is. The way I avoid this is to have custom classes with the data you need, and map them to the entity classes. This way, the rest of your system outside the project with the db model in it does't know what entity framework is, just what the new classes you define are. You can then have some sort of service or mapper class that exposes methods that return new objects to the rest of your system.